# Orthographic viewport zooming

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm a bit new in opengl so please bear with me. I have a viewport window like this

[image]

I have implemented zoom in/out features using the arrow keys. The problem is it zooms in and out with the whole image. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can make the GUI on the sides stay in place while making my viewport (the white rectangle) zoom in and out?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use separate projection matrices for the viewport and GUI.

E.g:

```
SetupViewportProjection();
DrawViewport();
SetupGUIProjection();
DrawGUI();
```